# How to generate parent child relation data from networkx to work with d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, networkx

I want to generate the parent child relation data from python networkx. I am using a multidigraph. I want to use the below javascript to generate my graph in html format:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184.

The data needs to be in some format as like in the flare.csv file mentioned in the link above.

So, my question is how can I generate the data from networkx as like above parent.child relation data?

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well, I am fairly new here. So if I am not making clear about my question, then I am sorry. Now say for example I have a multidigraph in networkx where Node1 is connected to Node1_1, Node1_2, Node1_3 and so on. And again Node1_1 is connected to Node1_1_1, Node1_1_2 and so on. So I want to generate a printout like below from G.nodes() and G.edges() printouts: Node1, Node1.Node1_1, Node1.Node1_2,Node1.Node1_3,Node1.Node1_1.Node1_1_1, Node1.Node1_1.Node1_1_2 and so on. This format is easy to use in the d3.js as I had mentioned previously in the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Let's create a graph (technically, a tree) based on your description:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
nodes = ['n0', 'n1', 'n1_1', 'n1_2', 'n2', 'n2_1', 'n2_2', 'n2_1_1']
edges = [('n0', 'n1'), ('n0', 'n2'), 
     ('n1', 'n1_1'), ('n1', 'n1_2'),
     ('n2', 'n2_1'), ('n2', 'n2_2'),
     ('n2_1', 'n2_1_1')]

G.add_edges_from(edges)
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
```

You should first get the root of the graph, and then traverse from root to every single node.

Root is the only node with in_degree zero, so:

```
root = [k for k, v in G.in_degree().items() if v == 0]
# ['n0']
```

Next, calculate shortest path from root to every leaf. We need to have a list of node which excludes the root.

```
all_but_root = [i for i in nodes if i not in root]
res =[]
for i in all_but_root:
    res.append(nx.shortest_path(G, root[0], i))
```

Additionally, if you want a painless way to get the output with correct format, you can use following code:

```
for i in res:
    txt = ""
    for j in i:
        if j != i[-1]:
            txt += j + "."
        else:
            txt += j + ","
    print (txt)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the codes. It is near to what I want, but not exactly as I am looking for. I am looking for the following result:
n0,
n0.n1,
n0.n1.n1_1,n0.n1.n1_2,
n0.n2,
n0.n2.n2_1,
n0.n2.n2_1.n2_1_1

I have generate a simular result for my case as below: 
['CORPORATE_FW1_SERVER1.DNS_SERVER1.CORPORATE_FW2_SERVER1.BUSINESS_SERVER1.CONTROL_FW1_SERVER1.CS_AUTHENTICATION_SERVER2.CONTROL_FW2_SERVER1.APPLICATION_SERVER2.GENERATOR_RTU1',
]
so I want like below:
'CORPORATE_FW1_SERVER1,
'CORPORATE_FW1_SERVER1.DNS_SERVER1,
'CORPORATE_FW1_SERVER1.DNS_SERVER1.CORPORATE_FW2_SERVER1, so on.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer based on your comment, is that what you are looking for?